# Jmeter Assertion failed

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, web-service

[image: Test results as advised by Dimitri T]Can any one help to resolve this?

[image]?

[[[image: ![]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzyPj.png)[[image: ][1]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGgDo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/683eP.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your Response Assertion scope to **Response Code**

[image: Assertion Response Code]

Your default **Text Response** setting looks for `200` in the whole response body, HTTP status code isn't included into the body therefore your assertion fails.

It will also make sense to change "Pattern Matching Rules" to **Equals** to avoid matches in case when response code will be 2000 (unlikely though)

More information on using JMeter Assertions: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

Comment: @ Dmitri T how to print pass fail result

Comment: Where do you want to print it? Normally if sampler is successful - assertion has passed and vice versa

Comment: @ Dmitri I want to print test result in assertion result ?

Comment: If you **really** need this, how about [Assertion Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Assertion_Results) listener? However using listeners during load tests isn't recommended as they cause resources overhead, see [Greedy Listeners - Memory Leeches of Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) article for more details.

Comment: im using this assertion listner but it will print HTTP request every time so i want to fix it?